# Python regex to get all the words in a tweet that are not @mention or #hashtag

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to get the words of a tweet that are not a mention (starting with @) or a hashtag (starting with #).

my code is like:

```
import re
pattern=r'(?u)\b\w\w+\b'
pattern=re.compile(pattern)
pattern.findall('this is a tweet #hashtag @mention')
```

The result with this regex is
***this is a tweet hashtag mention***

but I don't want the **hashtag** and **mention** in the result.
I want the result to be:

**this is a tweet**

Note that I can't use whitespace instead of \b because the output for
**.this is a tweet** (note the . at the beginning)
should also be 
[this, is, a, tweet]
\b forces the start of a word to be any non-alphanumeric but if I use \s then **this** won't be in the results.

Comment: Make the @ and # characters an optional prefix to your words, then filter the output after you apply the regex

Comment: I'm giving this regex to another function which is not mine (scikit-learn's tfidfvectorizer) so I can't do any post/pre processing, the regex should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<![#@])\b\w+\b
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/KzHvuy/2

Comment: Thanks, this works but given that the character before a word can be any non-alphanumeric as in .this is a tweet (which should return this as part of the result) I want something that excludes @ and # from \b.

Comment: one question @vks, do you know what that (?u) at the beginning of the original post regex does? (it is copied from sklearn).

Comment: @Afshin it means unicode characters are to be matched.Its flag for `unicode`

Comment: how can i add that to your regex? because i'll need that.

Comment: can I put it in from of your regex?

Comment: @Afshin you can add `(?u)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to solutions other than `regex`, then you can make use of `filter` and `lambda`  function for desired result.

```
a = 'this is a tweet #hashtag @mention'
" ".join(filter(lambda x:x[0]!='#' and x[0]!='@' , a.split()))
```

> 'this is a tweet'

Comment: Thanks, but have to give it to another function.